# Floating Header with Zoom to Top like theverge.com

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I am really fond of the floating header at [theverge.com](http://theverge.com). When you scroll down, the header stays fixed on top and when you scroll down to a certain point, The Verge logo appears which allows you to zoom back up.

How do I reproduce a similar header, can it be done with just HTML and CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this with CSS

```
.fixedHeader {
    position:fixed;
    top: 0;
}
```

the small button you should build with jQuery.
therefore you have to check the property **scrollTop** to know when the button should be shown. and if you click the button you should **.animate()** the scrollTop-property with jQuery back to zero (0).

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/algorhythm/VaFxU/)

And here with small button and click-event:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/algorhythm/VaFxU/3/)

Comment: Note: position:fixed is buggy but there are work-arounds.  Please read http://caniuse.com/#search=fixed and check the comments.

Comment: @algorhythm I salute you sir. You are awesome!

Comment: don't forget to include jquery.ui for the easing effects ;-) you can get it easily here http://scriptsrc.net